# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, dreamweaver, typeerror

I am trying to create a project that calculates the sum and average of a series of numbers input into a text field (separated by spaces). So in a single text box a user would enter "1 2 3" and what should happen is that I take the input, separate the numbers by the spaces and put the numbers into an array. Then add the elements in the array up to return the sum and calculate the average as well. However I am stuck on the adding part as I keep getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" in console when I run it. I have looked up other people who have had this issue but they seemed to be doing other functions and their fixes don't seem to work for me. I have attached my code in a picture here.

[image: Dreamweaver Code]

I have tried things like on line 13 of the javascript I change the `Number.numbers[i]` to `numbers[i].value` and that changes the output to NaN. I am quite stuck and would appreciate any help available. Thank you!

Comment: Please write the code. It is better than a picture.

Comment: do a parseInt with numbers[i].value  i.e. parseInt(numbers[i].value) and you should be through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To parse your string to number you need to do like this :

Number(your number).

So you will have to do like so :

```
sum += Number(numbers[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your don't change type of entered values.
When your get values from DOM element, you get string, but for calculate average your need type "number". Check your value with typeof operator. 
Or use my example to solve your problem

```
let input = document.querySelector("#inputId");
// now your numbers is array from values with type "number" after
parseInt
let numbers = input.value.split(" ").map((n) => parseInt(n, 10));
let sum = numbers.reduce((sum, number) => sum + number, 0);
let average = sum / numbers.length;
```